# Where is the best place to put rails functions that will be used by many controllers and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a lot of functions that I need to access in my controllers and views.

Where is the best place to put these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions used for view formatting across the whole application belong in the `ApplicationHelper`, however those helper functions should not perform any controller logic of their own.  In other words, they should not be responsible for invoking instances of models or doing anything much with them.

Functions that do invoke models, or functions that supply objects or data that will be used by other controllers, and act on them are more appropriately stored in the `ApplicationController`.  These would be functions like those needed to access application-wide login state in other controllers, for example.

Comment: Can functions defined in ApplicationHelper be accessed from views?

Answer (score 0):

the best place for such commonly used functions is application_controller.rb. I have used it to put code for checking if a user is logged in to determine if he/she needs to log in again.